# Mixed Content Warning with SSL on Concrete5

Tags: ssl, concrete5, concrete5-5.7

I have just installed a SSL certificate on my site that has concrete5 installed. I tried changing the canonical URL in the dashboard, just the SSL part to the https version of my site, and when I tried changing both it created a redirect loop so I had to undo it. The mixed content warning seems to be coming from the photos that I have on the site, Google Chrome informs me in the console that the photos and thumbnails are not using the https version, so it doesn't load them unless you specifically ask for it.

Comment: I'm not seeing a question here; if your images are served over http then you'll definitely get that warning.  Change your `href`s to https and it will go away.

Comment: Do you use `URL::to('/your/image/path')` to link to images?

Comment: I uploaded the photos through the concrete5 image uploader. The images display through the blocks, because some of the pictures are actually through featured content sections showing pictures of thumbnails of other pages. Is there a way to make concrete5 change all of its links to something else internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it! What I did, if anyone runs into the same problem, is I changed the Canonical URL settings in the dashboard to have the Canonical URL be the https version, the Canonical SSL URL be the https one, and have the redirect to canonical URL unchecked and it seems to be working now.